# jQuery: How do I remove a css border property from my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to remove the border of a div, but no luck.  I've commented out the code in my css and it is the correct property that I want to remove.  Here is the code I'm using currently. The background-color change is working that's in the code below but the removeClass is not.

```
var tab = getURLParameter("tab");

// Disable the visual style of the button since it is disabled for this page.
if (tab == "Property") {
    $(".scrape-button").css('background-color', '#efefef');
    $(".scrape-button:hover").removeClass('border');
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is your HTML? Do you actually have a border **class**?

Comment: Maybe try `$(".scrape-button").hover(function(e) { $(this).removeClass('border'); }, function(e) { $(this).addClass('border') });
`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery selector with hover pseudo class has no effect because there is no element in the page with hover state. I recommend you to try a different aproach

```
<script>
  var tab = getURLParameter("tab");

  if (tab == "Property") {
    $(".scrape-button").addClass("disabled")
  }
</script>
<style>
  .disabled {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
  }

  .disabled:hover {
    border: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: The only answer so far that is addressing the actual problem.

Comment: If what I said in the comment on my answer was correct, this is *exactly* what the OP wants!

Comment: @Vega Indeed, but the question wasn't at all clear as to exact requirements, provided this is what he does indeed want!

Comment: @rudi_visser So true.. sometimes it is really hard to understand what OP really is.

Comment: @coolxeo, worked perfectly. Thanks! Also thanks for the explanation I didn't know that my selector wasn't valid... (thanks for the others that pointed this out also!)

Answer (score 13):

Just remove the css property like this:

```
$(".scrape-button:hover").css('border','');
```

`.removeClass()` is used for removing a declared css class from element.

Comment: Really there is a `:hover` selector now? I thought you cannot trigger based on pseudo css.

Comment: @Adrian, That was something else I had tried and that didn't seem to work either...

Comment: @Vega I just repeated OPs selector (which seems to be working), my answer focuses on the `css` function

Comment: @Adrian I believe he mentioned that his 2nd `removeClass` wasn't working.. which could be either he is trying to `removeClass` or css border.

Comment: You are right, the issue is the selector. There's a better answer already, I'll delete mine

Comment: I think that doesn't suffice, you have to specify it's value as 0. ```$(".scrape-button:hover").css('border', 0);```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.scrape-button:hover').css('border', 'none');
```

Try this

Comment: Bam. Nailed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".scrape-button:hover").css('border','');
```

or

```
$('.scrape-button:hover').css('border', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no **:hover** pseudo class in jQuery..

Try this

```
$('.scrape-button').hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('border')
}, function() {
    $(this).addClass('border')
});​
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tHMzH/1/)
            ​

Answer (score 1):

Please try if you are using class--

```
$(".scrape-button:hover").attr('class','');
```